# Point of Sale/CRM for computer repair businesses

Tags: software-rec

Starting up a mobile computer repair company and I am looking at POS/CRM solutions.  I am trying out Commit CRM, but am looking to find other solutions that are out there to compare with.

Features I consider important are:

- Web interface
- Inventory management
- Multiple employees (fingers crossed)
- Asset tracking (tracking customers' equipment)

Who do you recommend?

Comment: severfault question? Try http://www.serverfault.com

Comment: This question is valid for SU. However you would possibly get a good set of answers on SF. So I suggest posting it on both.

Answer (score 3):

I use quickbooks for my business, it's not computer repair and I don't have a retail location. I do training, and my class site is not permanent. Most all of my customers pay on site or send in a check. I have my laptop which I also use for the presentation and take a printer for certificates and receipts. Several of the quickbook versions have employee, and payroll support, as well as POS "computer as a cash register"

I would use simple start, until you need the additional features the other versions give you.

You can buy simple start at retailers for $99 however you can download it for free from quicken.com

[compare products](http://quickbooks.intuit.com/product/accounting-software/quickbooks-comparison-chart.jsp)

[Simple start free download](https://oe.quickbooks.com/start/login.cfm?bc=QBF-FRE&trkr2=Z0N-0QB-00B)

Answer (score 2):

I'd check into Microsoft's Dynamics system if I were you.  Their CRM appears to be very good and can be accessed from anywhere through a web interface.  From what I can see, they should have some POS stuff included, but if not, then they at least have the integration capabilities to get POS up and running.

Answer (score 1):

I've had great results with [OpenBravo POS](http://www.openbravo.com/product/pos/) and you could hook it up with OpenBravo. It might be a little overkill for what you need but both are great products